# Microsoft peering-- EXPRESSROUTE

Tags: azure, networking, cloud

I became interested in Azure and while studying and answering questions, i'm really confused about this question.

ExpressRoute "Microsoft Peering" enables customers to: (select all that apply)

A. Connect to their virtual network resources from on premises
B. Connect to internet resources securely
C. Connect to Office 365 Services
D. Connect to Azure Services

I think it is B only not really sure.

I found this online
"Microsoft peering
Microsoft 365 was created to be accessed securely and reliably via the Internet. Because of this, we recommend ExpressRoute for specific scenarios. For information about using ExpressRoute to access Microsoft 365, visit Azure ExpressRoute for Microsoft 365.

Connectivity to Microsoft online services (Microsoft 365 and Azure PaaS services) occurs through Microsoft peering. We enable bi-directional connectivity between your WAN and Microsoft cloud services through the Microsoft peering routing domain. You must connect to Microsoft cloud services only over public IP addresses that are owned by you or your connectivity provider and you must adhere to all the defined rules. For more information, see the ExpressRoute prerequisites page.

Answer (score 0):

it is A, Express Route is used when you want a secured but also a speedy and committed connection your Azure region of choice. This way the connection from your organization's on-prem network is not only secure but also fast as you go from on-prem to your Telco then Hub to your Azure region. ExpressRoute is available for both Azure and Office 365 services.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that all the answers are correct